# Single build multi deployment for docker image created from Springboot+Angular Jar

Tags: angular, spring-boot, docker, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

I have a spring boot+ Angular application built as single jar, which is then updated to a docker image and deployed to openshift.

To make single build multi deploy for angular I have added configuration to config.json file under assets which during spring boot build is moved to static folder and a jar is generated.

I want to change the file at run time to have environment specific values and to be mapped to a config map in openshift which contains the values.

Can anyone please advise on how this can be achieved?

Comment: See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72786556/7381844)